# Does GitHub traffic insights include me?

Tags: github, repository

If I visit my own repository, while signed in, does it include that visit on the trafic graph for my repository? What about clones? I'm wondering because I can't tell if people are actually viewing my repository, or if it's just me.

Comment: Looks like the behavior might have changed, I posted a new answer in the linked question.